# @PreRemove/@PreUpdate JPA annotations in super and sub classes

Tags: jpa, event-listener, superclass

after upgrading to JPA 3.1 I encountered a problem.
I have super class A entity what has @PreUpdate and @PreRemove methods annotations coming from jakarta.persistence.

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
class A {
...
@PreRemove
private void preremoveLogic() { ... }
@PreUpdate
private void preUpdateLogic() { ... }
}
```

I have also classes B and C that inherit Class A

```
class B extends A {
...
@PreRemove
private void preremoveLogicForB() { ... }
@PreUpdate
private void preUpdateLogicForB() { ... }
}

class C extends A {
...
@PreRemove
private void preremoveLogicForC() { ... }
@PreUpdate
private void preUpdateLogicForC() { ... }
}
```

My IDE mark @PreRemove and @PreUpdate methods in subclasses as error:
*'PreRemove' entity listener method is already defined in class 'B/C' or in one of its superclasses*

And here comes my question: can I override somehow those methoeds from superclass in subclasses, to have @Pre methods in every classes?

Comment: You can have multiple events fire for the same entity. Check out JPA section 3.5.5. "Multiple Lifecycle Callback Methods for an Entity Lifecycle Event" for the rules and order. Overriding though is more difficult, but would follow method override rules on an entity instance.

Comment: Thanks @Chris , so it seems that this is IDE problem, because it recognize multiple lifecycle callback methods as an error.